# How to build libx11-dev from source?

Tags: linux, x11, configure, xlib

I have a stupid question.

I'm trying to install the 32-bit development packages of Xlib on a 64-bit CentOS machine, for which I don't have root. Therefore, I'm thinking of compiling myself from the source code (https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libx11).

I managed to resolve the 32-bit dependencies and, with the following commands, installed libx11 to my user folder.

```
git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libx11.git
cd libx11
~/bin/autoreconf --install --force
./configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu CFLAGS=-m32 CXXFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32 --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

Here are the files installed.

```
ls ~/lib/
.            libXau.a           libxcb-damage.la    libxcb-dri2.so.0      libxcb.la            libxcb-record.la        libxcb-res.so.0          libxcb-shm.a     libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0     libxcb-xinerama.la        libxcb-xkb.so.1    libxcb-xvmc.so.0
..           libXau.la          libxcb-damage.so    libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0  libxcb-present.a         libxcb-record.so        libxcb-res.so.0.0.0      libxcb-shm.la    libxcb-xf86dri.a     libxcb-xinerama.so        libxcb-xkb.so.1.0.0    libxcb-xvmc.so.0.0.0
libX11.a         libXau.so          libxcb-damage.so.0  libxcb-dri3.a         libxcb-present.la        libxcb-record.so.0      libxcb-screensaver.a     libxcb-shm.so    libxcb-xf86dri.la    libxcb-xinerama.so.0      libxcb-xtest.a     libxcb-xv.so
libX11.la        libXau.so.6        libxcb-damage.so.0.0.0  libxcb-dri3.la        libxcb-present.so        libxcb-record.so.0.0.0  libxcb-screensaver.la        libxcb-shm.so.0  libxcb-xf86dri.so    libxcb-xinerama.so.0.0.0  libxcb-xtest.la    libxcb-xv.so.0
libX11.so        libXau.so.6.0.0        libxcb-dpms.a       libxcb-dri3.so        libxcb-present.so.0      libxcb-render.a         libxcb-screensaver.so        libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0  libxcb-xf86dri.so.0      libxcb-xinput.a       libxcb-xtest.so    libxcb-xv.so.0.0.0
libX11.so.6      libxcb.a           libxcb-dpms.la      libxcb-dri3.so.0      libxcb-present.so.0.0.0  libxcb-render.la        libxcb-screensaver.so.0      libxcb.so        libxcb-xf86dri.so.0.0.0  libxcb-xinput.la      libxcb-xtest.so.0      pkgconfig
libX11.so.6.4.0      libxcb-composite.a     libxcb-dpms.so      libxcb-dri3.so.0.1.0  libxcb-randr.a           libxcb-render.so        libxcb-screensaver.so.0.0.0  libxcb.so.1      libxcb-xfixes.a      libxcb-xinput.so      libxcb-xtest.so.0.0.0  python2.7
libX11-xcb.a         libxcb-composite.la    libxcb-dpms.so.0    libxcb-glx.a          libxcb-randr.la          libxcb-render.so.0      libxcb-shape.a           libxcb.so.1.1.0  libxcb-xfixes.la     libxcb-xinput.so.0        libxcb-xv.a
libX11-xcb.la        libxcb-composite.so    libxcb-dpms.so.0.0.0    libxcb-glx.la         libxcb-randr.so          libxcb-render.so.0.0.0  libxcb-shape.la          libxcb-sync.a    libxcb-xfixes.so     libxcb-xinput.so.0.1.0    libxcb-xv.la
libX11-xcb.so        libxcb-composite.so.0  libxcb-dri2.a       libxcb-glx.so         libxcb-randr.so.0        libxcb-res.a        libxcb-shape.so          libxcb-sync.la   libxcb-xfixes.so.0   libxcb-xkb.a          libxcb-xvmc.a
libX11-xcb.so.1      libxcb-composite.so.0.0.0  libxcb-dri2.la      libxcb-glx.so.0       libxcb-randr.so.0.1.0    libxcb-res.la           libxcb-shape.so.0        libxcb-sync.so   libxcb-xfixes.so.0.0.0   libxcb-xkb.la         libxcb-xvmc.la
libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0  libxcb-damage.a        libxcb-dri2.so      libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0   libxcb-record.a          libxcb-res.so           libxcb-shape.so.0.0.0        libxcb-sync.so.1     libxcb-xinerama.a    libxcb-xkb.so         libxcb-xvmc.so

ls ~/lib/pkgconfig/
.   x11.pc  xau.pc        xcb-damage.pc  xcb-dri2.pc  xcb-glx.pc  xcb-present.pc  xcb-randr.pc   xcb-render.pc  xcb-screensaver.pc  xcb-shm.pc   xcb-xf86dri.pc  xcb-xinerama.pc  xcb-xkb.pc    xcb-xvmc.pc
..  x11-xcb.pc  xcb-composite.pc  xcb-dpms.pc    xcb-dri3.pc  xcb.pc      xcb-proto.pc    xcb-record.pc  xcb-res.pc xcb-shape.pc        xcb-sync.pc  xcb-xfixes.pc   xcb-xinput.pc    xcb-xtest.pc  xcb-xv.pc

ls ~/share/
.  ..  aclocal  autoconf  doc  emacs  info  man  pkgconfig  util-macros  X11  xcb

ls ~/share/pkgconfig/
.  ..  xorg-macros.pc  xtrans.pc
```

However, I don't know how to build the development version (libx11-dev or libx11-develop). Are libx11-dev coming from the same source code or I need to find some other source code? Alternatively, should I pass some specific options to ./configure?

Hope some one can help. Thank you!

Comment: The "development" version is just a subset of what you have already built with the addition of including the required headers and pkgconfig files. So the `-dev` package isn't so much something different you have to build, as it is just collecting the parts necessary for a user to include the needed headers and find the libraries so they can use them. It's a distro specific thing. openSUSE does `-dev` sub-packages, Archlinux doesn't - they just include it all with the original library package.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks David! I see. I think some header files have been installed as well under ~/include/: cursorfont.h  extensions  ImUtil.h  Xauth.h  Xcms.h  XKBlib.h  XlibConf.h  Xlib.h  Xlibint.h  Xlib-xcb.h  Xlocale.h  Xregion.h  Xresource.h  Xtrans  Xutil.h. I'm actually trying to compile Wine, which still can't find libx11-dev. How can I tell Wine that I have these files? Can I create some file like libx11-dev.pc under pkgconfig/ myself?

Comment: You see the pkgconfig (`.pc`) files. Those along with the `./include` files and the libraries are generally what make up the `-dev` package. What wine needs to know is (1) where the include files are which you specify with `-I/path/to/include` and (2) they need to know where the libraries are `-L/path/to/libraries` and then (3) they need to know which libraries to use with `-lname`. The kicker is libraries need to be in a standard location so they can be found when the program starts. You can hack that with `-Wl,rpath=/path/to/lib` to link that info or put the libs in a std place.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I see. Thank you! I found there's options provided by Wine configure scripts to specify include and lib file locations: --x-includes and --x-libraries